# Tkinter Adaptive text and dimensions

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

How can i make an app in tkinter with the text size and dimensions that will adapt to, and fit on smaller PC sizes? For example in other languages, you can specify text size and dimensions as percentages. Is there a way to do this in python 3? I'm using tkinter as my gui toolkit

Comment: Are you asking about a single label, or a whole GUI such as a word processor or forms to be filled out?

Comment: I mean all elements in the GUI window. The text size, the frame widths, width on entry boxes, size of images,e.t.c. when I use the app on lets say a mini-PC, only part of it fits on that small screen. I want it to adapt and everything to fit no matter the screen size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to [make a theme or styles](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-style-layer.html) where you apply a scaling algorithm set by yourself. Here is a simple example with just a button.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

# Base size
normal_width = 1920
normal_height = 1080

# Get screen size
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

# Get percentage of screen size from Base size
percentage_width = screen_width / (normal_width / 100)
percentage_height = screen_height / (normal_height / 100)

# Make a scaling factor, this is bases on average percentage from
# width and height.
scale_factor = ((percentage_width + percentage_height) / 2) / 100

# Set the fontsize based on scale_factor,
# if the fontsize is less than minimum_size
# it is set to the minimum size
fontsize = int(14 * scale_factor)
minimum_size = 8
if fontsize < minimum_size:
    fontsize = minimum_size

# Create a style and configure for ttk.Button widget
default_style = ttk.Style()
default_style.configure('New.TButton', font=("Helvetica", fontsize))

frame = ttk.Frame(root)
button = ttk.Button(frame, text="Test", style='New.TButton')

frame.grid(column=0, row=0)
button.grid(column=0, row=0)

root.mainloop()
```

It will depend on what type of widgets you use, on how to apply this to your GUI. For example tk.Button is different than ttk.Button. From what I have understood ttk widgets are better when it comes to native appearance than the tk widgets, but I haven't tested this myself.

To apply this to a complete GUI, you'd need to look into the different widgets you use in the GUI and see where you can do scaling. And you'll need to tweak the scale_factor to get it to look good. You can test out different "screen sizes" by setting screen_width and screen_height to resolution by your own choice.

Here is a style and theme [tutorial from TkDocs](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html)