# Tkinter toplevel window adaptive size with screen

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel

I'm trying to creat a python interface with tkinter.

The code is done on my laptop so every element's size (frame, label, entry, button, text font size, etc.) was created to fit my laptop's screen. I places all elements by grid.

But when i run the script on another computer with smaller screen size, i could not see the whole interface.

Is there any way in tkinter to automatically resize (reduce text size, frame size, entry size) to fit the interface to the screen size.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Nope, not at tkinter's level. Your laptop's OS probably has options to scale entire screen. You could of course code that in, like have a constant `FONT_SIZE=20` or something in your code so that it's easy to customize.

Comment: Hi Novel,

My laptop is under Win 10. What do you mean about the option to scale entire screen.  I couldn't reduce the size of my  tk window on another pc.

By the way, i've found this post :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32959571/tkinter-adaptive-text-and-dimensions

Comment: By scale the screen I mean basically changing the monitor resolution to the same or bigger than your other computer. The answer you found is good, it's an extension of what I mentioned with using a constant except the value is calculated based on the screen size.